# longtable: hline doesn't display on the first page

Tags: header-footer, longtable

table head and `\hline` do not display on the first page, as shown the red line below.

[image]

Here is the source code.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|l|}
    \caption{The throughput improvements achieved by network coding in Toulouse}
    \label{table:throughput improvement 2}
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    line1   &   line2   &   $t_1$       &   $t_{12}$    &   $t_2$       &   $r$(\%)&    $D$(GB)&    $D_{nc}(GB)$&$G_t$(\%)&Station\\    % table head
    \hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \hline
    \endfoot %  to appear at the bottom of each page
    10  &   2       &   0:22:00 &   9:46:00 &   2:00:00 &   80.49   &   159.18  &   302.25  &   89.88   &   Cours Dillon    \\
    10  &   109 &   1:19:00 &   8:55:00 &   1:40:00 &   74.93   &   188.48  &   319.09  &   69.3    &   Malepère    \\
    % more data is here
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

If I remove `\endfirsthead`, it raised the following error.

[image]

Comment: Put `\\\hline ` before `\endfirsthead`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, thx but it doesn't work:-( The result is totally the same.

Comment: Works fine for me. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add content of the `head` also to the `firsthead`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|l|}
    \caption{The throughput improvements achieved by network coding in Toulouse}
    \label{table:throughput improvement 2}\\ %<-- added
\hline%<-- added
line1 & line2 & $t_1$ & $t_{12}$ & $t_2$  & $r$(\%) & $D$(GB) & $D_{nc}(GB)$ & $G_t$(\%) & Station\\  %<-- added
\hline%<-- added
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    line1   &   line2   &   $t_1$       &   $t_{12}$    &   $t_2$       &   $r$(\%)&    $D$(GB)&    $D_{nc}(GB)$&$G_t$(\%)&Station\\    % table head
    \hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \hline
    \endfoot %  to appear at the bottom of each page
    10  &   2       &   0:22:00 &   9:46:00 &   2:00:00 &   80.49   &   159.18  &   302.25  &   89.88   &   Cours Dillon    \\
    10  &   109 &   1:19:00 &   8:55:00 &   1:40:00 &   74.93   &   188.48  &   319.09  &   69.3    &   Malepère    \\
% more data is here
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note:* The code, as it is, will not repeat caption on the new page.

Comment: thx a lot. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Put `\\\hline` before `\endfirsthead`:

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|r|r|r|r|r|r|r|l|}
    \caption{The throughput improvements achieved by network coding in Toulouse}
    \label{table:throughput improvement 2}
    \\\hline
    \endfirsthead
    \hline
    line1   &   line2   &   $t_1$       &   $t_{12}$    &   $t_2$       &   $r$(\%)&    $D$(GB)&    $D_{nc}(GB)$&$G_t$(\%)&Station\\    % table head
    \hline
    \endhead % all the lines above this will be repeated on every page
    \hline
    \endfoot %  to appear at the bottom of each page
    10  &   2       &   0:22:00 &   9:46:00 &   2:00:00 &   80.49   &   159.18  &   302.25  &   89.88   &   Cours Dillon    \\
    10  &   109 &   1:19:00 &   8:55:00 &   1:40:00 &   74.93   &   188.48  &   319.09  &   69.3    &   Malepère    \\
    % more data is here
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]